# The elements does not reach the edges

Tags: html, css, css-float

Hello I started learning html,css recently and when I was doing an exercise I faced a weird problem
[the picture of my desgin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ7oa.png)

when I was doing it I see my first p element never reaches the edges but the others does why? I tried to change he z-index use position and floating btu none of them worked

css style  & html:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
    overflow: auto;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    clear: both;
}
p.text {
    clear: right;
}
p.title {
    float: right;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 33.33%;
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font: bold 1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background: blue;
    background-size: cover;
}
#normal {
    background: white;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
div {
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    div {
        margin: 1.66%;
        width: 30%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Menu</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Our Menu</h1>
    <div id="normal">
      <div><p class="title">Chicken</p><p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eos ex hinc integre, utroque iracundia voluptatum sit ei. Eam ancillae suscipit id, pro exerci cotidieque at. Quo mazim molestiae maiestatis at. Simul solet timeam mea ex. At duo docendi eligendi, eius dissentiet eloquentiam id vel.</p></div>
      <div><p class="title">Beef</p><p class="text">Pri saepe ceteros menandri at. Mutat minim efficiendi et sed, aeque movet dolore vel cu. Pro harum delectus ponderum te, pertinax sententiae sit ut, vim hinc laudem alienum ei. Nam probo prompta at, no mea omnesque interpretaris.</p></div>
      <div id="third"><p class="title">Sushi</p><p class="text">Pri docendi apeirian te, ius ferri veritus deterruisset an. Te vivendo definiebas has, eu sea fierent platonem intellegebat. Pri et debet partem necessitatibus, utinam altera per cu. No sit omnium qualisque, ea vis placerat suavitate. Convenire conclusionemque te quo, dolorum corrumpit vel no. Ex vim legere insolens.</p></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean get the first p element to be aligned to the right ?  if so change the value of text-align here

```
p.title {
    text-align: center;
}
```

to this value

```
p.title {
    text-align: right;
}
```

while getting rid of z-index and keeping the rest of the code .

Comment: Hello, sorry but it didn't work fi you look at the photo I put there is a small distance between the balck border of outer div and the title chicken